# Pass php dynamic variable to shortcode

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I am not sure if there is a simple solution to my problem. The requirement looks simple but unable to find answer even after breaking my head for 6 hours. 
I have to pass variable from a php function to a shortcode and this shortcode has to pass on the this variable to another shortcode. Shortcode-1 will open a popup and the content of the popup is created by shortcode-2, content has to be changed based on the variable. How can I acheive this?

Code in my template..

```
 <a href="#" class="open-popup-1" variable= <?php getid(); ?>"> <?php  echo "Click here"?> </a>
```

popup shortcode:

```
[modifycontent id=$variable]
```

My shortcode function

```
function modifycontent($atts = [], $content = null)
{
// do something to $content

 $var = atts['id']; 

 $content = gettherightcontent($var); 
 return $content;
}
add_shortcode('mc', 'modifycontent');
```

I tried like this, I managed to call my shortcode but unable to pass the variable.

Comment: show us what you've tried. This is possible, but we need to have a place start.

Comment: okay.  adding an answer.  I'm not sure if I completely understood, but i'll clarify if I missed, so let me know.

Comment: Thanks for corrections and sorry for not being clear. My problem is in passing the value from html to shortcode.
In the example, I have mentioned html code (href) calls shortcode [open-popup] which calls my shortcode [mc]. [open-popup] shortcode is provided by plugin Popupbuilder. 

What works now, is when I click on "Click here" my shortcode[mc] gets executed. What I am not able to do is pass the variable from my template(html code) to my shortcode[mc] using popupbuilder in between.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors in your code...

1. on the html, there was no quotation in front of variable
2. on the php you say you were calling the short code [modifycontent] but by your php you should have been using [mc].

All the same,  here's how I would do it:

```
function modifycontent ($atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
         'id' => '1',
        ), 
      $atts );

    return '<a href="#" class="open-popup-1" variable="'.$a['id'].'">Click here</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'mc-shortcode', 'modifycontent' );
```

this would use the short code [mc-shortcode] to return:

```
<a href="#" class="open-popup-1" variable="1">Click here</a>
```

If you used this for the short code:  [mc-shortcode id='1']

it would return:

```
<a href="#" class="open-popup-1" variable="2">Click here</a>
```

(Notice the variable changes)